# How to get rid of double conda prompts?

Tags: python, conda

Recently I installed micromamba, and git cli on top of my existing mini conda environments.  Subsequently I am getting double prompts in the anaconda powershell window.

[image: double prompts]

I have uninstalled the git cli,tried to rename files in the micromamba folder so they would not be found, uninstalled miniconda and reinstalled it.  all of these have failed to address the problem.I also have a existing version of VS code.  Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this?  I can find No help on the web, and only one other instance of the problem.  I already need to rebuild my environments.  Is there a "Best way" to start over?  currently installed Windows 11, VS Code, Spyder, miniconda, mambaforge, micromamba.

Comment: In Unix such behavior would involve code to `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, or `.zshrc`. Not sure what the Windows equivalent is (can also depend on terminal).

Comment: @merv In PowerShell, IIRC it's the [Prompt function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.4), which can be specified in [one of the PowerShell profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)

Comment: @merv thank you!  It appears that micomaba  altered to  .ps1 file for my user profile before conda kicked in and loaded the loaded the env again on top of the already invoked profile/env.  My description belies the fact that I don't really grasp all that is going on but it seems to have addressed the issue.  I  simply prevent the profile.ps1 from being in my user\*\WindowsPowerShell directory.. Thanks again!